# Execute current Rmarkdown chunk and move to next one in RStudio

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

RStudio has a native feature (and keyboard shortcut) to run the **next** chunk in Rmarkdown and move the cursor to it (`Ctrl + Alt + N`). I'd like to be able to run the **current** chunk and move the cursor to the next one. I just want to run each chunk successively, without skipping the first one, and by seeing what I'm about to run. Is there a way to do that? Do I have to write an addin?

Comment: You may read this "https://www.dataquest.io/blog/r-markdown-tips-tricks-and-shortcuts/" It has the answer to your question.

Comment: @Stat-R this link is not helpful. it does not have answer to the question (at least I could not find). if you know the answer, can you please write the answer ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a late answer. but still useful for someone looking for it.
Start with `ctrl + alt + c` and then keep hitting `ctrl + alt + n`. It will do what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of the existing `Execute Next Chunk` command has bothered me for quite some time.

One workaround that executes the *current* chunk and then moves to the beginning of the next chunk uses the [shrtcts](https://pkg.garrickadenbuie.com/shrtcts/) package, which lets you assign Keyboard Shortcuts to arbitrary `R` Code, in combination with the `rstudioapi` package:

1. Use the command `shrtcts::edit_shortcuts()` in the RStudio Console to open the file where you define your custom shortcuts.
2. Paste the following code inside that file (set your preferred keybinding in the `@shortcut` line):

   ```
   #' Run Current Chunk and Advance
   #'
   #' @description Run Current RMarkdown Chunk and Advance to Next Chunk
   #' @interactive
   #' @shortcut Ctrl+Shift+Enter
   function() {
     rstudioapi::executeCommand(commandId = "executeCurrentChunk")
     rstudioapi::executeCommand(commandId = "goToNextChunk") |>
       capture.output() |>
       invisible()
   }
   ```

   This solution uses the native pipe `|>` and thus requires `R 4.1`.
   You can of course just define separate variables in each line or use the     `magrittr` pipe if you use earlier versions of `R`.
3. Use the command `shrtcts::add_rstudio_shortcuts(set_keyboard_shortcuts = TRUE)` in the RStudio Console to add the new shortcut with its assigned keybinding. Then restart RStudio.

One potential downside of this approach is that you cannot press e.g. `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` multiple times in advance even though the first chunks are still running since the line

```
rstudioapi::executeCommand(commandId = "goToNextChunk")
```

gets executed only after

```
rstudioapi::executeCommand(commandId = "executeCurrentChunk")
```

has finished.